# Display hamburger menu when mobile platform else desktop nav bar using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am just building a home page for displaying sensors data , I am not a web developer I picked bootstrap framework for the convince of designing less painstakingly, however I am not able to get hamburger menu work when I open the page on phone, if I open the page on desktop I want normal nav bar but when I open it on phone I want just the hamburger menu button that should display the items of nav bar when pressed.

Here is the code I have :

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <style>
    body {
        padding-top: 70px;
        font-family: "Roboto Slab","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

        /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
    }

    .no-border {
        border: none;
        background-color: white;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
.color-no-focus {
        color: grey;
    }
  .hover:hover {
        color: blue;
    }
 .white {
        color: white;
    }


.btn-circle {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42;
  border-radius: 32px;
  float: right;
}

    #container1
    {
      margin-bottom:10px
    }

    </style>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<!-- jQuery Version 1.11.1 -->
<!--script src=" vendor/jquery/1.11.1/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script-->
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataDisplay.js"></script>

</head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Access Home Online</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="index.htm">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="settings.htm">Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="connected-sites.htm">Sites</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

and this is what I am getting on my phone:
[image: mobile view]

in mobile view I do not want the above 3 links.

Comment: Got my wires mixed... mind sharing the URL? or got a JSFiddle?

Comment: The problem will be because your markup is incorrect you have two `navbar` when it should be one. The siblings of navbar should be something like `collapse navbar-collapse` not navbar within navbar, since navbar is the menu.

Comment: Can you explain what you want it to look like on the Desktop? since it's that what is confusing since from your code it looks like you want breadcrumbs above the menu bar on desktop, is this true?

Comment: I want a Hamburger menu for mobile platform and other menu for desktop.

Comment: So let me see if I got this correct? On the desktop you want breadcrumbs above the brand Access Home Online, or is the brand hidden and just the breadcrumbs?

Comment: on desktop I just want breadcrumb menu not the hamburger menu button ! hamburger menu button should only show up on mobile platform .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue why the Hamburger is not working is because you have two `navbar` classes, you can only once and only on the parent container. Since you want a breadcrumb layout then the easiest method would to use two different menus, one for desktops and one for mobile devices. It's not the best method but one that would work good, if you have the good CSS knowledge and patience you could remove the additional menu and re-work the CSS using media queries to mimic the same style as offered by class breadcrumb.

*Here's the HTML code that works:*

```
<header>
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a class="breadcrumb-item" href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="breadcrumb-item" href="settings.htm">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a class="breadcrumb-item" href="connected-sites.htm">Sites</a></li>
  </ul>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Access Home Online</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="settings.htm">Settings</a></li>
          <li><a href="connected-sites.htm">Sites</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

*Here's the CSS to go with this HTML:*

```
@media(max-width:767px){
  header .breadcrumb {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media(min-width:768px){
  header .navbar {
    display: none;   
  }
}
```

A updated jsFiddle can be seen [working online](https://jsfiddle.net/SimonHayter/vo1npqdx/251/)... to test the various modes resize the window of the results to emulator different devices sizes.

*The purpose of the 3x icon-bar classes*

The reason bootstrap uses 3x icon-bar spans is because the hamburger icon is made up of 3 lines using CSS, for each line you have this in the CSS:

```
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
```

Each line is 22px long, 2px in height and has a border radius of 1px.

Comment: what is the purpose of the 3 `<span class="icon-bar"></span>` under __Toggle Navigation__ 
This hamburger menu is showing up on mobile devices as well as on desktop, I wanted only nav bar to be visible in case of Desktop

Comment: I've updated the code and jsFiddle. The menu differs based on the viewpoint of the device (resolution)... this is how Bootstrap works as well as most other frameworks such as Zurb Foundation. If you want to detect mobiles and desktops differently then Bootstrap default menu is not for you... and your have to find a JS solution which won't be covered in this question.

Comment: If you want the breakpoint smaller.... then change 767px to 640px and 768 to 641px etc.